# CAML Join Value does not fall within expected range

Tags: csom, joined-view

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I have two lists:

Rating Sections:

1. Title - Single line of text

Rating Categories:

1. Title - Single line of text
2. Rating Section - Lookup to Title of Rating sections

I am attempting to use CSOM to join and query the two lists.  Each lists only contains 10 items so I shouldn't be hitting any sort of size limit.  My code is as follows:

```
using (var spContext = new ClientContext("http://myserver/jointest")) {
    var list = spContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Rating Categories");
    var query = new CamlQuery {
        ViewXml = @"
<View>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name='ID' />
        <FieldRef Name='Title' />
        <FieldRef Name='Rating_x0020_Section' />
        <FieldRef Name='RatingSectionTitle' />
    </ViewFields>
    <Joins>
        <Join Type='INNER' ListAlias='RatingSections'>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Rating_x0020_Section' RefType='Text' />
                <FieldRef List='Rating Sections' Name='Title' />
            </Eq>
        </Join>
    </Joins>
    <ProjectedFields>
        <Field Name='RatingSectionTitle' Type='Lookup' List='RatingSections' ShowField='Title' />
    </ProjectedFields>
</View>"
            };
    var listItems = list.GetItems(query);
    spContext.Load(listItems);
    spContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Every time I run the code, I get the exception "Value does not fall within expected range".  Any idea what I have wrong here?

Edit:  I've also tried it with the following values:

```
<FieldRef Name='Rating_x0020_Section' RefType='Id' />
<FieldRef List='Rating Sections' Name='ID' />
```

Which still throws the same error.  I've also tried every variation of capitalizing ID in both FieldRefs just in case it was case sensitive.

Comment: could you please recheck your field types. This exception might occur due to breaking the limitation "Moreover, the field in the primary list must be a Lookup type field that looks up to the field in the foreign list." according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.joins.aspx

Comment: The best I can tell, the field types are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer.  The List in the second FieldRef has to be the same as the ListAlias, so it should be:

```
<FieldRef List='RatingSections' Name='ID' />
```